# ST-Link cli in windows

Tags: command-line-interface, hardware, st-link

Link_cli.exe** and **stlink-tools** on Linux ubuntu

i have these command

**for windows:**

```
ST-LINK_CLI.exe -c sn=57004800180000535448534E -q -ME -p C:\shared\TFL_CONNECT_A4_S.10.118.0.16.hex -Rst
```

**for linux:**

```
st-flash --format ihex --serial 57004800180000535448534E  write C/shared/TFL_CONNECT_A4_S.10.118.0.16.hex -Rst
```

when i run it on windows its giving me this **ERROR**:

**No ST-LINK [ID=57004800180000535448534E] Found!**

when i run it on Linux its **working perfectly**

**its the same hardware the same connections same in every way**, the only **difference** is only the **OS**

**do anyone have an idea on what might be the problem ?**